# adjust gap between the lines in R console

Tags: html, r

When I parse web sites in R, (system: R+debian) the html object output in the console make me uncomfortable.

The gap is wide between lines. How can I make it normal, to narrow the gap between the   lines?

Maybe you can see tha same output with the following code.

```
options(encoding="gbk")
library(XML)
baseURL <- "http://www.jb51.net/article/27174.htm"
txt <- readLines(baseURL)
txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, it seems that when `print`-ing a vector, the longest element decides how all elements will be spaced.

Your longest string is `txt[374]`: on my screen, it takes 19 lines; that means every element of `txt` will be printed using 19 lines, with possibly a lot of white space.

You don't have that problem when printing a list, so a solution is to do:

```
print(as.list(txt))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I didn't test the code. `t(txt)` work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `gsub()` for replacing space by nothing.

Comment: His data has no blank lines, the problem is the way `print` presents it.