# paste() function in R: what happens when the input is a character vector?

Tags: r

I'd like to understand how `paste` handles input vectors.

Specifically, I wonder why I see two blank spaces between `"che"` and `"fai"`

```
> paste(c("ciao", "che", "fai"))
[1] "ciao" "che"  "fai"
```

Comment: The way you called the function it returned the vector as is. Try `> paste("ciao", "che", "fai")` to get `"ciao che fai"`.

Comment: Also read the rules, english language only on this particular stack site.

Comment: The two spaces are not related to the function ```paste```, but to the way a vector is printed to your console. Try ```c("ciao", "che", "fai")``` and you will have the same result. You can also try ```c("ciao", "che", "faaaaaaaaaaai")``` and see the difference. R checks the lenght of the elements to decide how to print stuff https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246869/adjust-gap-between-the-lines-in-r-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not related to how `paste` works.
Rather it's related to how `print` works.

When you launch the command `paste(c("ciao", "che", "fai"))`, what you see in console is actually the output of `print(paste(c("ciao", "che", "fai")))`.

In this case, `paste` doesn't change your input at all, therefore it's like launching the following command: `print(c("ciao", "che", "fai"))`.

`print` default behaviour for character vectors makes each string the same length (the same number of characters) and then writes them in console.

In your case each string has to be as long as the longest string (`"ciao"`) which is 4 characters plus two times `"`. Strings that are not that long are filled with blanks.

Here I created a function that breaks down what `print` actually does to your input:

```
my_print <- function(x){ 

  # set up " " around strings
  x <- dQuote(x, q = FALSE)
  
  # make all the same length
  x <- format(x, width = max(nchar(x))) 
  
  # print with the same style of `print`
  cat(x, fill = TRUE, labels = paste0("[", seq_along(x), "]"))

}
```

What you see in console:

```
> my_print(c("ciao", "che", "fai"))
[1] "ciao" "che"  "fai" 

> print(c("ciao", "che", "fai"))
[1] "ciao" "che"  "fai" 

> c("ciao", "che", "fai")
[1] "ciao" "che"  "fai" 

> print(paste(c("ciao", "che", "fai")))
[1] "ciao" "che"  "fai"
```

Note the length of each string:

```
[1] "ciao" "che"  "fai" 
    ------+------+------
    123456+123456+123456
```

Comment: Perfect answer !

Answer (score 0):

This is not realted to how paste works, but to the fact how an output is printed to the console in R. Try `print(c("ciao", "che", "fai"))`. You should get the same result. To understand better the behaviour, you can try `print(c("a", "aaaa", "a", "a", "a"))`.

Comment: Quello che mi chiedo non è come ottenere la stringa "ciao che fai", cosa che posso fare passando collapse = " ", ma il perché dei due spazi generati dalla funzione specificata nella mia domanda. Quindi, il comportamento della funzione paste() quando passo un solo vettore di stringhe di diverse lunghezze.

Comment: Agree with @desval. I tried paste(c("a", "aaaa", "a", "a", "a")). It separetes the first from the second with 4 spaces, then uses only one space and then continues using 4 spaces. I agree this behaviour is a bit strange though.

Answer (score 0):

The `paste()` function concatenate the elements of the vector. The reason for the space in between the concatenated elements is that the standard value for the argument `collapse` is `" "`. In case you want to concatenate the elements directly you can use `paste(c("ciao", "che", "fai"), collapse = "")` -> `"ciaochefai"`

Comment: This is wrong. The default is ```collapse = NULL```. His code just prints back the input, no collapse is called.

Comment: Il valore di default di collapse è NULL, come è possibile vedere dalla documentazione. Infatti, se io scrivo paste(c("ciao", "che", "fai"), collapse = " ") l'output che ottengo è "ciao che fai". Quindi non ottengo i due spazi tra le stringhe "che" e "fai". Voglio capire il motivo dei due spazi invocando paste(c("ciao", "che", "fai")).